# No "chapter" text for one chapter in tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I currently have the following ToC code:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\chaptername }

\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]{    
    \chapter*{#1}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ #1}
}
```

And section of the document are defined like this:

```
\likechapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\section{Some subsection}
```

It produces the following ToC:
[image]

I don't need "chapter" text for Introduction. If I change `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\chaptername }` to `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}`, it removes "chapter" from all chapters.  So, how can I remove only for some chapters (defined by `\likechapter`)?

EDIT: [minimal example](https://www.overleaf.com/read/mjbrcpffrbpp):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\chaptername }

\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]{    
    \chapter*{#1}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ #1}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\likechapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\section{Some subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post minimal but full examples that others can copy and test as is. Then it is a lot easier to help. And I don't think that is the proper `tocloft` way of prefixing entries in the toc, I do think it has an interface to add those without messing with a font setting.

Comment: @daleif I've added the link

Comment: Please don't place examples on external links, links rot over time and then your question will not be useful to others.

Comment: @daleif thanks, I've added whole text to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\cftchappresnum`  to add to word `Chapter`  before the chapter number. (note the space after).

Then enlarge the indent of the chapter title in that amount by expanding the number box.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }% space after Chapter

\newlength{\xtraspace}
\settowidth{\xtraspace}{\cftchappresnum} % extra space = Chapter + space
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\xtraspace} % makes  the indent of the  chapter title larger

\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]{%    
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
    \likechapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}
    \section{Some subsection}
    
\end{document}
```